# Task executor Spring integration - Subsequent service activators are executed as a part of the pool

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am wrting a spring application where I am using 2 task executors. So structure of my code is as below

```
<!--
Web gatherer Configuration 
-->

<int:channel id="web-gatherer-channel">
    <int:queue capacity="10"/>
</int:channel>
<task:executor id="webGathererExecutor" pool-size="10" queue-capacity="10"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="web-gatherer-channel" ref="webGatherer" method="getData"
                       output-channel="aggregator-router-channel">
    <int:poller task-executor="webGathererExecutor" fixed-delay="500">
    </int:poller>
</int:service-activator>


<!--
    Webgatherer  Configuration - END
-->

 <!--
SQL Gatherer Configuration - Start
-->
<int:channel id="sql-gatherer-channel">
    <int:queue capacity="10"/>
</int:channel>
<task:executor id="sqlGathererExecutor" pool-size="10" queue-capacity="10"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="sql-gatherer-channel" ref="sqlGatherer" method="getData"
                       output-channel="aggregator-router-channel">
    <int:poller task-executor="sqlGathererExecutor" fixed-delay="500">
    </int:poller>
</int:service-activator>


<!--
SQL Gatherer Configuration - END
-->
 <int:chain input-channel="aggregator-router-channel">
    <int:aggregator ref="aggregator" method="aggregate" message-store="resultMessageStore"
                    release-strategy="gathererRelease"
                    correlation-strategy="gathererCorrelationStrategy"
                    correlation-strategy-method="getCorrelationKey">
    </int:aggregator>

    <int:router ref="generatorRouter" method="route"/>
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="XLS-channel" output-channel="mailSender-channel">
    <int:service-activator  ref="xlsGenerator" method="generate"/>
</int:chain>
```

So the flow is as below

Message -> splitter - > 1. Web gatherer 2. SQL gatherer -> Aggrgator -> XLS generator

Currently my XLS service activator should run independently But in logs I can see it is running under one of the task executor which is random.

```
JxlsGenerator:sqlGathererExecutor-4 transformXLS execution in 166 ms
```

I am not able to understand why it is running as part of the task-executor pool.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a result of the `<int:aggregator>`. It receives messages from different threads and when it is ready to release a group, it collects a result and emits it from the thread it has met a release condition. That's how your `XLS-channel` is called or from one or from another thread.

Well, actually any code in Java is called from some thread. When we develop single-threaded app with only `main()`, all the code is called from that `main` thread. If you don't change thread, the program is performed in the current thread.

If you would like to have `XLS-channel` on it own, independent thread, then consider to make this channel as an `<executor>`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-executorchannel.

And also read about Java threading model.

Comment: Thanks @Artem. I will make xls-channel as executor channel.